# How to give a user access to sys.master_files in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to give a database user read access to the `sys.master_files` table. How can I do that?

Currently the user has this permissions:

[image]

Calling `SELECT` on `sys.master_files` returns an empty result. I also tested the same query with the `sa` user which works as expected.

Comment: The [relevant Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) - available **freely** to anyone - clearly states what permissions are needed for the `sys.master_files` catalog **view**: *The minimum permissions that are required to see the corresponding row are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION.*

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know how to apply this rights in the GUI.

Comment: They are server level permissions, not database level permissions, click the securables section in the screen you were in when you took the above screenshot and you will see them.

Comment: Thanks! Feal free to add your comment as an answer in order I can accept the anser.

Answer (score 10):

for you to run successfully

```
select * from sys.master_files
```

the minimal permissions that you need to grant is as follows:

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [texas_user]
GO
```

I have tested and it works fine on sql 2008 r2

```
regards
marcelo
```

Answer (score 0):

Those server level permissions can also be added by T-SQL script such as :

```
use master
grant ALTER ANY DATABASE  to [texas_user]
grant VIEW ANY DEFINITION to [texas_user]
grant CREATE ANY DATABASE to [texas_user]
```

The result will be the same: user `texas_user` will be able to receive results from the `sys.master_files`. But probably those abilities are some much more than you want. May be, you can receive the same results querying the `sys.database_files` in the user databases (*`texas`*, *`TexasLog`*).

Comment: Small remark. The above code you need to execute with the `sa` privileges